Counting filtered rows of a table
How can I count the filtered rows of a table. The table has many rows. It is just normal containing many rows. With the help of following Javascript code. I filter data, by way of typing into input text, pasting the required value and also with a click to import the value from OptionList; and all these three ways are functioning perfectly.  If it is possible to amend this code so as to get the count of filtered rows out of total rows, i.e. "Found ... rows out of ... rows", at the top of table. I am totally a new user of javascript without any previous knowledge so sorry for that. The code is :
const trs = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", filterRows);
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("change", filterRows);
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", filterRows);

function filterRows(e) {
  const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  for (const tr of trs) {
    tr.style.display = tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(query) ? "" : "none";
  }
}


Details are commented in the example.


// Reference <input type="search">
const srch = document.querySelector("#search");
// Reference <output>
const msgs = document.querySelector("#message");
// Gather all <tr> into a NodeList
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

/**
 * This event handler matches the text to the text of each
 * <tr> while the user is typing.
 * @param {object} e - Event object
 */
const findTerm = e => {
  // Convert search term to lower case
  let term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  // Iterate through the <tr>
  rows.forEach(tr => {
    // On each <tr> convert it's text to lower case
    let text = tr.textContent.toLowerCase();
    // If a match is found...
    if (text.includes(term)) {
      // remove the .hidden class from <tr>...
      tr.classList.remove("hidden");
      // otherwise add the .hidden class to <tr>
    } else {
      tr.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  });
  // Get the amount of tr.hidden
  let hid = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden").length;
  /* 
    If there at least one tr.hidden, display a message 
    announcing the totals, otherwise display nothing.
  */
  msgs.value = hid > 0 ? `${rows.length - hid} 
  out of ${rows.length} matched the term: "${term}"` : "";
};
/*
  Register input#search to the "input" event.
  Registering it to the "change" and "click" events is
  pointless, "input" event covers what "change" and 
  "click" does as well.
*/
srch.addEventListener("input", findTerm);
  
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

table,
td {
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

input, 
output {
  display: block;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin: 5px auto;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
}
<input id="search" type="search">
<output id="message"></output>
<table>
<tbody><tr><td>Microsoft</td></tr><tr><td> Google</td></tr><tr><td> Apple</td></tr><tr><td> Amazon</td></tr><tr><td> Facebook</td></tr><tr><td> Netflix</td></tr><tr><td> Adobe</td></tr><tr><td> Salesforce</td></tr><tr><td> Oracle</td></tr><tr><td> IBM</td></tr><tr><td> Intel</td></tr><tr><td> Cisco</td></tr><tr><td> HP</td></tr><tr><td> Dell</td></tr><tr><td> VMware</td></tr><tr><td> Twitter</td></tr><tr><td> Uber</td></tr><tr><td> Airbnb</td></tr><tr><td> Dropbox</td></tr><tr><td> Slack</td></tr><tr><td> Tesla</td></tr><tr><td> SpaceX</td></tr><tr><td> Reddit</td></tr><tr><td> Pinterest</td></tr><tr><td> Zoom</td></tr><tr><td> Shopify</td></tr><tr><td> Square</td></tr><tr><td> PayPal</td></tr><tr><td> LinkedIn</td></tr><tr><td> Etsy</td></tr></tbody></table>




That is so fantastic, fast, to the point and brief. Works like a charm. Thank you so much! . Although the input text box not functional when on-clicked-transferred value from the option list in a  separate . But the code is excellent and meets the need.

@M.Rono I'm glad it helped. I'm not sure what an option list exactly is, but if you add some more code including it, I'll either add it in as a separate function or fit it in with the same handler -- whatever seems more efficient.

On same html page, there are two divs . One contains main table and other contains list of words in option list. The words are one way or other related to main table. When from option list, a word is selected it sends directly to input box of table with a separate code. But once  input box gets the word from option list, the input box does not respond.  i think  with the line ofthe code with  srch.addEventListener("input", findTerm); another like  srch.addeventlistener may work. thanks

Hi @M.Rono that sounds more or less like a <datalist>.

it is not  , rather it is Chocolate  without value=!!!

with a small addition of one line in the code, the functionality materializes, albeit with a mouse click inside the input. I modified the code with srch.addEventListener("click", findTerm);, now it is working perfectly,  It is just like treat in a mouse click. thanks a lot.

When you query the DOM with something like getElementsByTagName(), it returns a collection of elements.  This collection has the length property, so if you wanted to know how many rows you had in total, you could just use trs.length.  Though you still need to get the count that's visible after filtering.
I would do something different in your code.  I would add a class for filtered to your CSS:
.filtered {
  display: none
}

Then, in your loop:
function filterRows(e) {
  const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  for (const tr of trs) {
    tr.classList.toggle('filtered', !tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(query));
  }
}

That will add/remove the filtered class as appropriate.
Then, if you want the count...
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.filtered)').length

One final note... I'd recommend avoiding the usage of IDs.  They clutter up the global namespace and can cause conflicts when you add code later on.

thanks for reply. If u please amend the code so it can be pasted there. I am really new and no nothing of adding these lines. sorry and thanks.

@M.Rono I don't really understand... paste the CSS in your CSS and the JavaScript in your JavaScript.

I have inserted filtered in style section CSS and replaced the function filter row with your code, but still filtered row counting not  being shown. that was the reason I requested to your help to amend total code to be pasted. thanks.

@M.Rono This isn't a free rent-a-coder service.  StackOverflow is where you come to learn, sharing questions and answers so that others can learn as well.  There's nothing wrong with just starting out and asking questions of course, but you will have to make an effort to adapt answers to your code, and learn from those answers.

@Brad, excellent answer, with best use of toggle function and minimal code. Please just correct the typo document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.filtered)').length instead of document.querySelector('#myTable tr:not(.filtered)').length so that SO questioner  can reproduce the expected result

thanks. I came here to learn n did not take it as a "free rent-a-code-service", i really do not  know why you became so upset. you could easily have ignored my post. Anyhow no problem, i respect u and thanks again for your guidance n advice.

@Mehdi Thank you, and thanks for catching that bug.  Fixed.

In your code you're using for loop. You can define a variable named counter and in that for loop you can increase the counter's value by 1 in each iteration. And finally you can show that data.


const trs = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", filterRows)
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("change", filterRows)
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", filterRows)

function filterRows(e) {
  let counter = 0;
  const query = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  for (const tr of trs) {
    counter++;
    tr.style.display = tr.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(query) ? "" : "none"
  }
  
  document.querySelector("#output").innerText = counter;
}




You should reset counter to 0 every time you call filterRows(). Otherwise the count will keep going up every time you call it.

@Barmar Thanks, changed the code accordingly.

This code filters a table to value of inputs and shows rows and count.


let tableHNDL=document.querySelector("#myTable");
document.getElementById("searchValue").addEventListener("input", filterRows);
document.getElementById("selectOptionList").addEventListener("change", filterRows);
document.getElementById("searchBTN").addEventListener("click", filterRows);

function filterRows(e) {
    let searchFor=e.target.value.toLowerCase(); // gets the elements value. selectOption & textbox & button.
    //let searchFor=document.querySelector("#searchValue").value;
    let rowsFound=0;

for(let a=0;a<tableHNDL.rows.length;a++){
for(let b=0;b<tableHNDL.rows[a].cells.length;b++){
if(tableHNDL.rows[a].cells[b].innerHTML.toLowerCase()==searchFor)
{tableHNDL.rows[a].style.display="block";rowsFound++;break;}
else
{tableHNDL.rows[a].style.display="none";}
}
}

let rs=document.querySelector("#resultCount");
if(rowsFound){rs.innerHTML=rowsFound+" rows found.";}else{rs.innerHTML="Nothing found.";}

}
<table border="1" id="myTable">
<tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td></tr>
<tr><td>a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td></tr>
<tr><td>a3</td><td>b4</td><td>c3</td></tr>
<tr><td>a4</td><td>b4</td><td>c4</td></tr>
</table>

<select id="selectOptionList">
<option value="c4">c4</option>
<option value="a2">a2</option>
<option value="b1">b1</option>
<option value="c3">c3</option>
</select>

<input id="searchValue" type="text"/>

<input id="searchBTN" type="button" value="a2"/>

<div id="resultCount"></div>



